# Sybase: if-else error

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I have the following if-else statement in SAP Interactive SQL (Sybase):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects o, sysusers u WHERE o.uid=u.uid AND o.name = 'mytable' AND u.name = 'user1')
    BEGIN
        PRINT "Dropping table mytable"
        DROP TABLE mytable 
        PRINT "Dropped table mytable"
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT "Table mytable does not exist" 
        SELECT * INTO mytable FROM mytable2
        PRINT "Table mytable copied from mytable2"
    END
```

Error message:

```
"Could not execute statement. There is already an object named named 'mytable' in the database."
```

If I get rid of the else clause it checks for the table and if it exists it drops it as expected. But together with the else clause it chooses that last one whether the original table exists or not. Hence the error message that the table already exists. What is the problem here? I think I got the syntax right (taken from the sybase documentation and other sources).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID("mytable") IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE mytable
GO

SELECT * INTO mytable FROM mytable2
```

EDIT1:

```
IF OBJECT_ID("mytable") IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE mytable

EXEC ("select * INTO mytable FROM mytable2")
```

Comment: This solution works, although I'm not really happy with it for the following reasons: 1. Neither the Sybase documentation nor any other sources I consulted use the EXEC version. 2. The EXEC statemente doesn't seem to work for PRINT or SELECT. Maybe I doing something terribly wrong but this es as far as I got.

Answer (score 0):

Case here is that for `mytable` user owner is not `'user1'`. So code from `ELSE` block is executed and because `mytable` still exists it fails. Try:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects o WHERE  o.name = 'mytable' AND o.type = 'U')
```

and

```
EXEC('DROP TABLE mytable')
```

You can also follow a different way to make conditional drop:

```
if (object_id('mytable') is not null)                                      
    EXEC('drop table mytable')
```

Comment: Didn't work, still the same error. Actually, the isolated select statement does find the correct table entry in 'sysobjects' and returns a resulting table with a single '1' (I think should be taken as "true").

Comment: Exists will return True for nonempty result set. Could you provide result of query following query:SELECT name,type FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'mytable'?

Comment: The result of that query is: name: `'mytable' type: 'U' (1 rows)`

Comment: Can you just drop 'mytable'?

Comment: Yes, I can manually drop it. I can even drop it with the if clause if the else clause is not present but both at the same time doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Good point in @Meet's solution, entire query won't run because during precompilation mytable exists, even the in real execution it not.